# Comparing value of cells from two different sheets

Tags: vba, excel

First my code:

```
   Option Explicit
Sub UpdateCandidates()
  Application.ScreenUpdating = False
  Dim wks As Worksheet, wks2 As Worksheet
  Dim Lastrow As String, Lastrow2 As String
  Dim Rng As Range, i As Long, Rng2 As Range, i2 As Long
  Dim cell As Variant, cell2 As Variant

  Set wks = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Candidates")
    Lastrow = wks.Range("B" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
    If Lastrow > 1 Then
      cell = wks.Range("B2:B" & Lastrow).Value
      i = 1: Set Rng = Nothing
            While i <= Lastrow
            For i = i To Lastrow
                Set wks2 = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Job live")
                        Lastrow2 = wks2.Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
                        If Lastrow2 > 1 Then
                            cell2 = wks2.Range("A2:A" & Lastrow2).Value
                            i2 = 1: Set Rng2 = Nothing
                            While i2 <= Lastrow2
                                For i2 = i2 To Lastrow2
                                    If cell = cell2(i2, 1) Then
                                        MsgBox ("found")
                                    End If
                                Next
                            Wend
                        End If

            Next
      Wend
    End If
  Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

This basically works and compares the two columns but at the end it shows an error:

> "Subscript out of range"

I don't understand why. I thought it's because of `<= Lastrow` but fixing to `< Lastrow` doesn't change anything.

I also would like to copy a value from the first sheet to the second one to a particular cell. And also insert a row below the cell from my second sheet.

I also don't understand why I have to compare cell to `cell2(i2,1)` and not cell to `cell2`. If I compare cell to cell2 it says type mismatch. And I have the same error if I enter a second value in my sheets.

What's wrong with my code?

Comment: Why loop over all worksheets if you only want to process the worksheet named "Candidates"? That seems like a pointless loop. Why not just `Set wks =ThisWorkbook. Worksheets("Candidates")`? Similar remarks hold for "Job live". You have two nested loops that can be replaced by simple variable setting.

Comment: @JohnColeman I did that but i don't know why it stays on the same sheet if i do that. And it's always the current active sheet.

Comment: @JohnColeman Oh wait i did it again, i didn't mention the "Set" so maybe that's why. Anyway i have deleted the for loops and set it like you said. It doesn't solve my problem tho

Comment: Usually I think it is helpfull to declare all your variables in one place, so that it is easy to identify them. Perhaps do it as one of the first things. It also makes your loops look cleaner, and therefore makes it easier to see when there is an error somewhere. Also at what row exactly does it show subscript out of range?

Comment: Cell2(i2,1) makes your comparison over all values in the range of cell2 that you identified earlier: `cell2 = wks2.Range("A2:A" & Lastrow2).Value` as `i2` identifies the row and `1` identifies the column

Comment: All the variables are already declared at one place. And here the row:                     If cell = cell2(i2, 1) Then

Comment: @Luuklag But then i don't understand why i can't compare cell(i,1) to cell2(i2,1). If i do this it says type missmatch.

Comment: why is `lastrow2` then declared halfway your loop?

Comment: @Luuklag ` Dim Lastrow As String, Lastrow2 As String` It is declared in the header

Comment: Ah then I messed up declared and set. Terminology isn't my strong part sorry. Anyway you could also move `Lastrow2 = wks2.Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row` to the top, as well as `cell2 = wks2.Range("A2:A" & Lastrow2).Value` as both do not depend on what happens in your loops.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see your code, and here's a proposal

```
Option Explicit
Sub CompareDefinedRanges()
Dim rng1, rng2 As Range
Dim found As Boolean
Dim i, j, foundAt As Integer
Set rng1 = Worksheets("Candidates").Range("B2", Worksheets("candidates").Range("B2").End(xlDown).Address)
Set rng2 = Worksheets("Job live").Range("A2", Worksheets("Job Live").Range("A2").End(xlDown).Address)
'show items
For i = 1 To rng1.Rows.Count
found = False
foundAt = 0
For j = 1 To rng2.Rows.Count
   If rng1.Item(i) = rng2.Item(j) Then
   found = True
   foundAt = j
   End If
Next j
   If found Then
   MsgBox rng1.Item(i).Value & " found at " & CStr(foundAt), , "Candidates"
   Else
   MsgBox rng1.Item(i).Value & " not found", , "Candidates"
   End If
Next i
Set rng1 = Nothing
Set rng2 = Nothing
End Sub
```

Comment: I've added another condition to not compare blank and deleted the else statement. But it takes too much time to compare. Excel end's up in no responding mode for 30s or more. It also only compares the first line of Candidates, i tried adding another candidates and it doesn't compare anymore after the first line

Comment: After some tests it works with some values but not with others. I copy paste them so i know its exactly the same. How is possible that it works only with some values?

Comment: I found why. The rng2.Rows.Count was only counting like the first 2 items and then it stoppes idk why. So i changed it by a number and it works. It compares everything

Comment: Hi, @J. Doe, the limits of the two for-cycle are static according the range pre-defined in the first lines, it is a property of range object that should work well. Let's do this, may this could be solved modifying changing the sentence to evaluate `If rng1.Item(i) = rng2.Item(j) Then`   to   `If rng1.Item(i).value = rng2.Item(j).value` , tell me please if this works for you